# Since the worsening in Android, many apps do not work more; is there a workaround (Android 12 on Galaxy 10+)?

Tags: usb, sd-card

The various apps show a preparing window saying, like, Permissions are to be granted in the next window (examples), do grant permissions by ...

[See my first screenshot].

Then the app switches to Android. Then there appears a window of a file manager. It has no name, no information where it comes from. I suppose that is what is often called "Android's internal file picker". This file manager is offered in many different cases but is not usable, it has two failures:

1. The one is that the listed files are not shown with their full names. Thus I cannot discriminate between the files. And their timestamp is needed with full time, but it is missing.

   [See my second screenshot].
2. The other failure is that the needed permissions for the storage device cannot be given.

[See my third screenshot as an example of the plugged-in SD card].

A popup window is placed just over the lines of the SD card data. Saying:

> This folder cannot be used, create a new folder.

What does this crazy advice mean?

I am about to continue my work with the SD card, but I should choose another storage device.

Comment: I cannot include pctures, have never done before. In /storage/emulated/0 -> pictures -> screenshots are .jpg. I can select on and choose "copy to clipboard" in filemanager X-plore. But in your form I can click the picture icon. Then a window ooens with a light blue button. If I click  in this button, nothing happens. Regards.

Comment: In your question you mention screenshots but these are missing. You should be able to select a screenshot file by clicking on `Browse` in the Stackexchange image helper available in the toolbar of the question editor. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/169461